# Is there a way to add a value from a specific column to the row before?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a possibility to loop through a DataFrame and extract a Value from one column and add it to the row before? Afterwards deleting this row, since otherwise not containing any information.

#### Original

| Index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text | text | text | text |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | Value | NaN |
| 3 | text | text | text | text |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | Value | NaN |

#### Output

| Index | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | string | string | string, Value | string |
| 3 | string | string | string, Value | string |

I guess that the First and last step have to be included, but I'm not sure what i could use to get the value into the previous row.

##### First step

Select rows where e.g. column A contains nan values.

```
df[df['A'].isnull()]
```

##### Intermediate step

Add Value in C to text in row before (e.g. 2C -> 1C)

```
?
```

##### Last step

Drop rows where e.g. column A contains nan values.

```
df.dropna(subset=['A'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected your source DataFrame, adding one row:

```
         A    B     C    D
Index                     
1       T1   T2    T3   T4
2      NaN  NaN  Val1  NaN
3       T5   T6    T7   T8
4      NaN  NaN  Val2  NaN
5      T10  T11   T12  T13
```

The first step is to compute a Series, stating which rows should be changed.

```
myRows = df.A.shift(-1).isnull() & df.C.shift(-1).notnull()
```

I assumed that:

- *A* column in the next row should be *NaN*,
- and *C* column in the next row should **not** be *NaN*.

The second step is to compute new values for the above ("wanted") rows:

```
newVals = (df.C + ', ' + df.C.shift(-1))[myRows]
```

The next step is to write them into *df.C*, with mask, to preserve other values:

```
df.C.mask(myRows, newVals, inplace=True)
```

And the last step is to drop rows containing *NaN* in *A* column:

```
df.dropna(subset=['A'], inplace=True)
```

The final result is:

```
         A    B         C    D
Index                         
1       T1   T2  T3, Val1   T4
3       T5   T6  T7, Val2   T8
5      T10  T11       T12  T13
```